# Flutter: smooth drawer transition for closing while navigating to another page

Tags: flutter, dart

Using Flutter v.1.22.5, I integrated a navigation drawer to my app (needs to be added to every page that should contain it, right?). After tapping on of the ListTiles, I call Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() inside the ontap() handler to navigate to another page inside my app.

```
            ListTile(
              title: Text('FooPage'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/foo'); //navigates to page and closes the drawer INSTANTLY
              },
            ),
```

The app then instantly navigates to the associated page but abruptly closes the navigation drawer - it instantly disappears without any smooth closing transition. Is this the normal behaviour of the Flutter navigation drawer or am I doing some silly mistake here? Isn't there any way to have the app navigate to the desired page in the background while smoothly closing the drawer?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pop your navigation to close the drawer, then use `pushReplacementNamed`. You can also add a delay if you want to wait a bit.

```
ListTile(
    title: Text('FooPage'),
    onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(); // pop the drawer
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/foo');
    },
),
```

With delay:

```
ListTile(
    title: Text('FooPage'),
    onTap: () async { // add async
        Navigator.pop();
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 150)); // wait some time
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/foo');
    },
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The first solution does not work as pushReplacementNamed() is executed while the drawer is being closed. Is has to be done with the delay (your second solution). Thanks for that, yet I still consider this a bug since we're talking about a native feature which obviously does not behave as expected.